# Get string from another class and set it to TextView

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have `LoginActivity` and I declared into this class string `String currentName`. I have a `WelcomeActivity` class and I would like to set this `currentName` in a TextView. How to do it? Now that I have the in `WelcomeActivity` class declare `LoginActivity loginActivity` and set it this way, but that doesn't work:

`TextView welcome;
welcome = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvWelcome);
welcome.setText (loginActivity.currentName);`

Thanks for help ;)

Comment: What is the current outcome? Do you get an Exception? Does the text just not change? Please add more information.

Comment: it means you have string in login activity and after login you are showing welcome activity and now you wan to show the string that was in login activity?

Comment: Make your `String currentName` to `public static String currentName` then try your code.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of keeping currentName as global variable you can send data though intent and get it in welcome activity

Create intent in the loginActivity and send the current name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("currentNameId", currentName);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the oncreate of welcome activity get the data that was sent.

```
String currentName = getIntent().getStringExtra("currentNameId");
```

And then set it to the textview

```
TextView welcome;
welcome = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvWelcome);
welcome.setText(currentName);
```

Comment: @Kima321 This is a proper way of doing what you are required. To make string static in activity is not a good way. Because it affects lifecycle of activity results in memory leaks as static variables life is life of your application whereas when you switch activity it lifecycle changes. For further study activity lifecycle in android.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Singleton class

```
public class MySingleton {

    private static MySingleton mySingleton;

    private String currentName;

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (mySingleton == null)
            mySingleton = new MySingleton();
        return mySingleton;
    }

    public String getCurrentName() {
        return currentName;
    }

    public void setCurrentName(String currentName) {
        this.currentName = currentName;
    }
}
```

From The LoginActivity set value to Singleton class

```
MySingleton singleton =  MySingleton.getInstance();
singleton .setCurrentName("<Name to Set>");
```

From the second WelcomeActivity access the value

```
MySingleton singleton =  MySingleton.getInstance();
singleton.getCurrentName();
```

Answer (score 0):

In LoginActivity just create static String

```
   public static String currentName= "test";
```

And in WelcomeActivity do like this

```
   welcome.setText(currentName);
```

**Note-:** but better way to pass values one activity to another activity using Intent.

// **LoginActivity**

```
  public void sendDataToNextActivity(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, WelcomeActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String strData= editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra("data", strData);
///OR  intent.putExtra("data", "test");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

// **WelcomeActivity**

Receive data in onCreate

```
 Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        String getDataFromFirstActivity;
        if (extras.containsKey("data") && extras != null) {
                getDataFromFirstActivity= extras.getString("data");
                welcome.setText(getDataFromFirstActivity);
            }
```

**Start Intent-**

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: @Kima you can also follow Anonymous answer.

Comment: Bro this can do the job but this is inappropriate way. It causes issues.

Comment: yes bro i know but at this time i have suggest to him use @Anonymous answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of static variable ,
you can use Intent,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, WelcomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("currentNameId", "here add your text which you want to display");
startActivity(intent);
```

than in welcomeActivity,
in onCreate method,

```
String currentName = getIntent().getStringExtra("currentNameId");
```

now set text in your textview,

```
welcome.setText(currentName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing a static variable in your LoginActivity and try to access it from another acitivty is **not** a good idea. You have to consider the activity lifecycle and the fact that the activity could *potentially* be destroyed by the system, and also the memory leak it will cause etc.

You can read some more on lifecycles here, https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

What you want to do is to pass the value as an extra in the intent, and then retrieve it from the intent in your second activity.

In your `LoginActivity` when your user have entered correct credentials and you're about to start your `WelcomeActivity` you want to create the intent for starting the second activity like this (adding the name as an extra):

```
Intent welcomeIntent= new Intent(context, WelcomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extra_current_name", currentName);
startActivity(welcomeIntent);
```

and then in your `WelcomeActivity` you retrieve that in your `onCreate()` method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String currentName = getIntent().getStringExtra("extra_current_name");
    TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvWelcome);
    welcome.setText(currentName);
}
```

Read up some about passing data between activities and building intents here, https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent

Answer (score 0):

```
//To send data to 2nd activity call this function or set it to button onclick.
public void onclick_next(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this,2nd_activity_name.class);
        i.putExtra("username",username); //2nd username has the text that you want to send.
        startActivity(i);
    }

//When you are in second activity,  To get send data from 1st activity, use this codes inside the oncreate method.
Bundle logonData = getIntent().getExtras();
      String username = logonData.getString("username");
      final TextView usernameText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUser);
      usernameText.setText(username);
```

Answer (score -1):

I make my string to `public static String currentName` and its work. Thanks guys :)

Comment: To make strings static in activities is not a good way. Proper way is to pass string via Intent.

Comment: @kima making a variable static and accessing it in other class would cause memory leak.Use intent to pass data as I suggested in my answer

Comment: @Anonymous yes mate it causes memory leaks and affects activity life cycle also.

Answer (score -2):

You definitely should not store an instance of you activity, because it can and will be recreated at some point by OS.
The simplest solution is to declare currentName as static member.

```
public static String currentName;
```

Afterwards you can access it by classname:

```
welcome.setText(LoginActivity.currentName);
```

If you open WelcomeActivity from LoginActivity, you can also use extras.

```
intent.putExtra(SOME_TAG, currentName);
getIntent().getStringExtra(SOME_TAG);
```

I guess the best solution will be to store this string somewhere in the [database](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid/wiki/Getting-started), [preferences](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) or atleast some [Singletone class](https://android.jlelse.eu/how-to-make-the-perfect-singleton-de6b951dfdb0).